# Using typescript for graphql hygraph

Tags: typescript, types, graphql

So i am using react and first time using it with typescript, currently building a blog using hygraph but after i query it i think something is wrong with how i defined my variables. I saw someone someone using @types/node but i still dont understand how to use it.

```
import { request, gql } from "graphql-request";

declare var process : {
  env: {
    GRAPHQL_API_ENDPOINT: string
  }
}

const graphqlAPI: string = process.env.GRAPHQL_API_ENDPOINT;

export const getPosts = async (): Promise<any> => {
  const query: string = gql`
    query Assets {
       //queries here
    }
  `;
  const result: any = await request(graphqlAPI, query);
  return result.postsConnection.edges;
};
```

and this is the env:

```
process.env.GRAPHQL_API_ENDPOINT = //api
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.env` file, add the variable like this -

```sh
GRAPHQL_API_ENDPOINT=//api
```

Notice there's no space. Modify your file to look like this -

```ts
import { request, gql } from "graphql-request";

const graphqlAPI: string = process.env.GRAPHQL_API_ENDPOINT!;

export const getPosts = async (): Promise<any> => {
  const query: string = gql`
    query Assets {
       //queries here
    }
  `;
  const result: any = await request(graphqlAPI, query);
  return result.postsConnection.edges;
};
```

Make sure that `@types/node` is installed and in your `tsconfig.json`'s lib option, there's a value `node` present in the array. That should take care of it.

Comment: OH! thanks so much i forgot i added a space by habit,  thank you sir